# glmnet- introduce cost function

Tags: glmnet, oversampling

I'm using `glmnet` to predict a binary class. I have only 16% of positive cases. Also **false negative ( I lose 90 USD) are 9 times more expensive than false positives (I lose 10 USD)**.

I thought that one way to introduce this in the solution algorithm is oversampling the positive class. But is this totally correct? **How can I introduce this cost matrix in `glmnet` algorithms**?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with **glmnet**, unless you can specify it via observation weights on the observations via the `weights` argument.

Comment: mmm. but I think that would be the same as doing oversampling, don't you think?

Comment: Possibly; I'm not familiar with this sort of thing.

Comment: why is `glmnet` different from `glm` in terms of using a cost function?